# Detecting the user's mouse over the edge of a Path2D shape on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, hover, jpanel, shapes

So, I am trying to implement a drag-to-resize functionality for a rectangle.

So, what I want is when the user is hovering over the bottom-right **corner** of the rectangle, to change the cursor to a two sided arrow. (Like when you resize Chrome) I'm not sure how to do this.

This is a simplified version of the program that just adds a square on the center of the screen. Anyone have any ideas on how I can implement this? Thanks

**Update**

I almost have it but the cursor is also changing when I am on the top-right of the rectangle. I want this only when it is on the bottom-right. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        int mouseX = e.getX();
        int mouseY = e.getY();
        Path2D hitShape = null;
        for (Path2D shape : shapes) {

            Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
            if (mouseY >= bounds.y && mouseY <= bounds.y + getHeight()) {
                int lowerX = bounds.x + bounds.width - 2;
                int upperX = lowerX + 4;
                if (mouseX >= lowerX && mouseX <= upperX) {
                    hitShape = shape;
                    System.out.println("Hit");
                    Cursor cursor = Cursor
                            .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR);
                    setCursor(cursor);
                    break;
                } else {
                    Cursor cursor = Cursor
                            .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
                    setCursor(cursor);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Full Code**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UMLEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new UMLWindow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 700);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class UMLWindow extends JFrame {
    Shapes shapeList = new Shapes();
    Panel panel;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UMLWindow() {
        addMenus();
        panel = new Panel();
    }

    public void addMenus() {

        getContentPane().add(shapeList);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        shapeList.addSquare(100, 100);
    }
}

// Shapes class, used to draw the shapes on the panel
// as well as implements the MouseListener for dragging
class Shapes extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Path2D> shapes = new ArrayList<Path2D>();
    int currentIndex;

    public Shapes() {
        MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
    }

    public void addSquare(int width, int height) {
        Path2D rect2 = new Path2D.Double();
        rect2.append(new Rectangle(442, 269, width, height), true);

        shapes.add(rect2);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        for (Path2D shape : shapes) {
            g2.draw(shape);
        }
    }

    class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();
            Path2D hitShape = null;
            for (Path2D shape : shapes) {

                Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
                if (mouseY >= bounds.y && mouseY <= bounds.y + bounds.getHeight()) {
                    int lowerX = bounds.x + bounds.width - 2;
                    int upperX = lowerX + 4;
                    if (mouseX >= lowerX && mouseX <= upperX) {
                        hitShape = shape;
                        System.out.println("Hit");
                        Cursor cursor = Cursor
                                .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR);
                        setCursor(cursor);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Cursor cursor = Cursor
                                .getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
                        setCursor(cursor);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The right edge is the `x+width`.  You will want to allow for a certain amount of give, say +/- 2 pixels around the edged...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I actually had an MCVE when I first posted but overwrote it with the updated code. Bad decision. Updated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like...

```
int mouseX = e.getX();
int mouseY = e.getY();
Path2D hitShape = null;
for (Path2D shape : shapes) {

    Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
    if (mouseY >= bounds.y && mouseY <= bounds.y + height) {
        int lowerX = bounds.x + bounds.width - 2;
        int upperX = lowerX + 4;
        if (mouseX >= lowerX && mouseX <= upperX) {
            hitShape = shape;
            break;
        }
    }

}

// Deal with the shape you just hit...
```

You may also be interested in taking a look at `MouseMotionListener` and changing the cursor/shape based on the position of the cursor...

**Updated with right-corner detection**

The right corner needs to match the x AND y position of the mouse, because you should allow for some "margin" around the point, you could simply use `mouseY >= bounds.y - margin && mouseY <= bounds.y + margin`, then you would determine which side the mouse is on...

```
int mouseX = e.getX();
int mouseY = e.getY();
Path2D hitShape = null;
for (Path2D shape : shapes) {

    Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
    // Upper edge...with buffer...
    if (mouseY >= bounds.y - 4 && mouseY <= bounds.y + 4) {
        int lowerX = bounds.x + bounds.width - 2;
        int upperX = lowerX + 4;
        // Right corner....
        if (mouseX >= lowerX && mouseX <= upperX) {
            hitShape = shape;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Around about now, I would be creating, at least, 4 methods, `isWithinTopEdge`, `isWithinBottomEdge`, `isWithInLeftEdge`, `isWithInRightEdge`, would took the path's bounds, the mouse `Point` and a margin value and would return `true` or `false`.  This way you could mix the checks in any order you want simply.

You could also use `Path2D#contains` it simplify the checks, but you'd need to allow for the fudge factor, but that's just an idea...

Comment: I was actually planning to use MouseMotionListener. On a mouse move, would I call the code you posted?

Comment: I almost have it but it is also changing on the top-right of the rectangle, too. Any idea why? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the answer. I am changing the cursor in this if statement: `if (mouseX >= lowerX && mouseX <= upperX)` and the cursor is changing on the entire right side of the triangle, not just the right bottom corner.

Comment: Actually, I got it work. Thanks a lot MadProgrammer, you've helped me so much with Swing the past few weeks!

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the whole right side, I'll update and we can compare ;)

Comment: Actually got it working but we can definitely compare. I'm trying to get this working for a circle but using getBounds won't exactly work because I want to get it on the outer edge of the circle, not on the edge of the bounds surrounding it. But that's another topic...Thanks again!